# How to apply before_filter to every action of every controller in Rails 3.2.11?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, redirect, before-filter

I'd like to verify if the user is logged in on every single request to the server.

Something like:

```
:before_filter verify_logged_in
```

Where should I put that before_filter so it applies to all controller actions and all requests?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To ensure that filters apply to all actions, place it in the application_controller.rb.

Comment: What if yo want to add an except for that filter? how would you run the filter for all actions in all controller except for let's say index action of users controller? @David Hahn

Comment: You would add: `skip_before_filter :verify_logged_in, :except => [:index]` to the users controller.

Answer (score 10):

Application Controller is the base class of all other classes.

If you put any filter in this class then the flow works as follows:

If you hit url say of `users` resource with any action say `index` action then:

The control first goes to `Application Controller`. There it checks for filters, if finds any then it executes the filter method and after that it goes to index action of users controller.

**Application Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :verify_logged_in

end
```

**Other Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end
```

Here in the above code you see that the other controller is inheriting the contents of parent controller which is application controller. So if you put `before_filter` in the application controller then for every user it will verify if the user is logged in for each request.

Comment: And what do I do when I use a lib like omniauth that doesn't use my application controller for its actions?

Answer (score 4):

put before_filter in the base class(in application_controller.rb file), it will work on base and all its derived classes, such as

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] or I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Place it in the `ApplicationController` and inherit all other controllers from it. If you don't overwrite `verify_logged_in` in one of your sub-controllers it simply works.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the filters to apply to all actions, place it in the controller your application controllers inherit fronm. (Default is `ApplicationController`)

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user 
  after_action :redirect_if_deleted
  
  # [...]
end
```