# Disable user timeout on specific controller action with Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I`ve on my Rails website a specific URL that is monitored by an user. It uses a WebSocket connection to keep updated but can stay long periods waiting for data. I currently use Devise Gem for user login control. Can I disable user timeout for this specific URL?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the timeout is controlled by Devise and not by the webserver?

Comment: In my User model I have the following:

 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:confirmable,:timeoutable

That makes devise responsible for the user timeout, right?

Comment: Yes. I changed the the devise config to 1 minute timeout and it worked. So it's really coming from it.

Comment: Rails devise was set to 30 minutes, so I changed it to 1 minute (just to check if it wasn't the server) and the user expired in 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this so I can't confirm it will work but you can try it out easily.

Add an attribute to your `User` model, something like `prevent_timeout`. Then, in the specific Controller and Action that you are talking about grab the `current_user` and set it to `true`. You should also add a [`before_filter` to your `ApplicationController`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752390/how-to-apply-before-filter-to-every-action-of-every-controller-in-rails-3-2-11) that sets `prevent_timeout` to `false` to ensure it always gets set back to false once the user navigates away from your special URL. Lastly, use the [dynamic timeout feature](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically) of devise to check whether `self.user` has `prevent_timeout` set to `true`. If it is `true` then set the timeout to a year (essentially never timeout). Otherwise, set it back to your default.

Comment: Cool. I'll try it and let you know if it worked. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome @Casanova feel free to accept the answer :)